# Is it safe to exceed a receptacle's rated voltage?

Tags: power

I'm trying to find a suitable receptacle for 750 V / 18 A DC, I'm looking at NEMA standards as they seem the most readily available and found that none are rated for higher than 600 V. I'm wondering if its safe to exceed the voltage rating by this margin if the current stays below the rating? I'm also unsure if it's safe/practical to use an AC receptacle like this for DC applications.

Thanks for taking to time to help

Comment: Voltage ratings are usually to avoid arcs, and are orthogonal to the current ratings. In general - no, it is not safe to exceed any rating.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist No, that is not a safe assumption to make. Just because the receptacle is rated to withstand _momentary_ peaks of 848V does not mean that it will safely handle that voltage continuously.

Comment: It should have different ratings for DC and AC which are not necessarily obviously correlated.

Comment: So the NEMA standard receptacle's aren't suitable, do you know of any receptacles fit for 750 VDC?

Comment: The DC requirements are usually to make it dust proof on the insulation surface, which can cause creepage arcs that can lead to arc flash in high energy sources.  One of these may be suitable or contact a major PV supplier. https://www.mouser.ca/Connectors/Power-Connectors/Heavy-Duty-Power-Connectors/_/N-axiuu?P=1yvsm2aZ1z0x652Z1z0wxeoZ1y92f3y&Ns=Pricing|0

Comment: That value is beyond the +20% test rating of a 600 VAC switch, which would be 720 VAC maximum. At 750 VAC the switch may arc badly when disconnecting a load, then things go BOOM!

Answer (score 2):

You should not exceed ratings. You should not use DC on a connector rated only for AC, nor should you use high frequency AC (eg. RF) on a connector intended for main use.

There are proper high voltage receptacles, however they will not be cheap. [Here](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/molex-llc/1714669001/WM17623-ND/4839793)  is one that appears to be aimed at applications such as electric vehicles.

[image]

Industrial ones such as those used in mines will likely be more dear again.

Comment: $192 for one side only $cdn

Answer (score 2):

NEMA standard connectors are, *by definition*, intended for use with AC only. Using any of these connectors for DC would be a safety risk, as it would allow a device which expects AC to be plugged into a connector that would actually supply DC.

What you are looking for is a "high-voltage DC" connector. Use this (or "HVDC") as a keyword when searching and you'll be more likely to find something appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

No 600Vac receptacles are not suitable for 750Vdc.

**The issue is dust and moisture contamination causing surface ion flow leading to ionization and short circuit arc**.

As indicated in comments PV connectors were the best bet for HVDC and high current.

This is [what I found.](http://www.windandsun.co.uk/products/Grid-Connect-Accessories/Solar-Cable-and-Connectors/Huber-Suhner-Connectors)

### Key factors for safety and low cost

- single conductor connectors
- environmentally protected and recessed contacts.
  [image]

C1-6/HSN    Huber +Suhner 6sqmm Radox twistlock negative connector femal    £1.00
C1-6/HSP    Huber +Suhner 6sqmm Radox twistlock postive connector male  £1.00

Huber + Suhner Radox solar connectors have the following features:

```
Small profile    
Integrated twist locking    
High current capacity    
Mechanically robust    
UV- and ozone resistant    
Protection mode IP 68 in mated condition    
Easy assembly    

Rating: 1000V, 38 A     
Temperature rating: -40°C...+85°C
```

Comment: While PV power connectors have the right electrical properties, there are some significant safety issues with using them here (which is why I removed them from my answer). These connectors are all single-pole, so two of them would have to be used to supply DC power. This would introduce the risk of the power source being short-circuited, or the device connected in reverse polarity, if the wrong pairs of PV connectors are linked together.

Comment: They are polarized plugs, that’s why they use them for DC and 10%~20% of other solutions

Comment: Only 4% of cost of @Spehro’s choice.

Comment: The connectors are polarized, but each connector only has a single pole, so two pairs of connectors would be needed to supply power to a device -- and there's nothing to prevent those pairs from getting mixed up.

Comment: 2 for input and 2 for output should not be a problem with labels and logical position of cable bundle.

Comment: 600V/20A is a lot of power. Enough so that correctly reading (and interpreting!) labels should not be required to ensure user safety.

Comment: Moreover: while using labels for safety-critical polarization might be (barely) acceptable in equipment made for personal use, it will certainly fail electrical safety certifications, so it's right out for any kind of commercial or industrial application.

Comment: How can one confuse a male female pair from a power source and short them together ought to be system problem easily solved with restraints .